# Spark - Watch data in Spark Console when running from Intellij IDE

Tags: apache-spark, intellij-idea

Using spark 3.2, and IntelliJ IDEA

Is there a way to watch Spark runtime information after running?
Data is reported once I run actions on `spark-shell` but I have a complete application I would like to watch its statistics there.

Is there a possibility to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Filesystem Case-Sensitivity Mismatch
The project seems to be located on a case-insensitive file system.
This does not match the IDE setting (controlled by property "idea.case.sensitive.fs")